# Java variable not being affected

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

Now this may sound like a question that has been repeated many times before but I've done a day of research with people that has other reasons for this Issue.

I have a function that reads a part of the save file and its been shown that it does receive the correct data. So the error is that the integer variable completely ignores the new variable and shows no change in the live debugger so like many other post it is not just a duplicate object error. I cant seem to pinpoint what is the main issue is here and it's the last major thing holding me back. Any help would be great and I'm very extremely sorry if I did manage to miss a topic about this on the internet.

Code that fails:

```
@Override
public void read(List<String> data) {
    //world positions are not being changed at all

    System.out.println(data.get(1)); 
    int test = Integer.valueOf(data.get(1).replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
    worldXPos = Integer.valueOf(data.get(0).replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
    worldZPos = test;
}
```

Another class that gives the data:

```
public void readSaveFunctions(){
    if(!gameSaves.exists()){
        gameSaves.mkdir();
    }
    String currentLine;
    try {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileReader read = new FileReader(currentFile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(read);

        String key = "";
        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
            if(currentLine.contains("#")){
                key = currentLine;
                data = new ArrayList<String>();
            }else if(currentLine.contains("*end")){
                for(int i = 0; i < saves.length; i++){
                    String tryKey = "#" + saves[i].IDName();
                    if(tryKey.equals(key)){
                        key = "";
                        saves[i].read(data);
                    }
                }
            }else data.add(currentLine);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Another way of explaining it is this:
Debugger is set to step - to - step mode so I see each line getting executed at human speed then I get to a line like this but all of the ones setting the variables have the same effect:

```
worldXPos = Integer.valueOf(data.get(0).replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
```

and the debugger shows the two integers having different numbers but the instant class variable stays exactly the same with no effect in the debugger after the line goes through.

Update:
I forgot to mention the method has a @override method and it seems that this @override may be causing this issue, now finally I may have a path to follow again

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there isn't enough here for us to help but *What I mean by that is the integer variable completely ignores the new variable and in the eclipse debugger watching the integer variable being assigned to a different number but just stays the same* **is not** coherent. What on earth does it **mean**?

Comment: do any of you guys need more of a example added on?

Comment: @furProgrammer No but we need a better explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my answer: The AWT thread manage to activate calling a method from another class that changed the integer before it could be read. It really though me off at first because the debugger only showed one of the threads and with no way to know the other one was actively changing it to early. Thanks for all the help :P.